# PDT autocomplete broken in Eclpise

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-pdt

Suddenly I can't use autocomplete in my Eclipse PHP projects.
When I press alt+/ I jsut hear a dummy sound.
Which settings should I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  Right-click your top level folder in PHP Explorer.  Select the "Configure" menu item then "Add PHP Support".

Answer (score 1):

Does you PHP Language Library include a link to your local PHP install?  Sometimes I've found my project gets corrupted, and that PHP gets stripped from that include.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, simply reloading Eclipse helped.

Comment: Also manually rebuilding the project sometimes does it - or invoking an action that will require a rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply choosing 'Project > Clean' restores auto/code completion. (Eclipse 3.7.0 Indigo with PDT 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed to re-create my workspace (was using a workspace from an older version of PDT). Copying then importing the projects into the new workspace still worked.